# Filter insults with a word list

Tags: php

I have a textarea or the persone enters its text and I would like to filter the insults (with a list of words) by replacing them with **** once the form validate but I do not know how to me take. Thanks for your help ^^

```
if (isset($_POST['Envoyer']))
{
....
}

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<P><b>Your message:</b><br/>
<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160"></TEXTAREA>
<input id="bouton" type="submit" style="color:black;" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="SEND"><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: English please????

Comment: Users will just find a way around it, and it'll give you lots of trouble. https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace all occurances of the insulting words with ***.
Create an array and store all insults in it and then iterate iver it replacing each on of them with ***.

**IN FRENCH**
Vous devez remplacer toutes les occurrences des mots insultants par *. Créer un tableau et stocker toutes les insultes en elle, puis l'itérer en remplaçant chacun d'entre eux par *

```
$userInput = $_POST['Envoyer'];
$insults = ["insult1","insult2"];
foreach($insults as $insult)
{
    $userInput = str_replace($insult, "****", $userInput);
}
```

**Update**
As @AbraCadaver pointed out:

you can also use:

```
$userInput = $_POST['Envoyer'];
$insults = ["insult1","insult2"];
$userInput = str_replace($insults, "****", $userInput);
```

as `str_replace` also accepts arrays.

**IMPORTANT**

Please use English for other members to be able to understand it.

Translation:

Veuillez utiliser l'anglais pour que les autres membres puissent le comprendre

Comment: Assuming English `ass` this would replace `assignment` with `***ignment` etc...

Comment: And just use `$userInput = str_replace($insults, "****", $userInput);` with no loop as `str_replace` takes arrays.

Comment: Upvote for a good suggestion. Will add to the answer

Comment: Sorry for the translation I had not seen that I had put the French version

Comment: Ty for your help :)